# how to append a div in click function using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**HTML**

```
<body>
<input type="button" value="ADD" class="add">
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="txt1">
        <input type="text" class="txt2">            
        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="del">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".add").on('click',function(){
       $(".cont").append$(".wrapper");
    }); 
 });
```

Hi frnds here if I click the add button the whole div has to append. I don't know whether i am going in right way or not. Please guide me.

Comment: `$(".cont").append($(".wrapper"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the modified script to work:

Please find preview here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SzVcBpNtujZ3iBSnX21n?p=preview

You need to append .html() function

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".add").on('click',function(){
     $(".cont").append($(".wrapper").html());
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`append$()` is not jQuery function

Chagne

```
$(".cont").append$(".wrapper");
```

to

```
 $(".cont").append($(".wrapper"));
```

OR

```
 $(".wrapper").appendTo(".count")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".add").on('click',function(){
    var item = $(".wrapper").eq(0).clone();
    $(".cont").after(item);
   }); 
 });
```

**EDIT :-**

Fiddle Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/cj575cey/1/

Comment: Hi @exception your code is when ever i click it is getting double.

Comment: @PranavCBalan..yes correct..but it should be '0' instead of '1'

Answer (score 1):

`.wrapper` is already wrapped by `.cont`.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".add").on('click',function(){
    $(".cont").append($(".wrapper"));//change append$(".wrapper") to .append($(".wrapper"))
   }); 
 });
```